# Publishing a mvc 5 app using Folderprofile does not work after copying it to Windows Server host

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I publish my app to a windows server I get a weird problem. Seems like the app thinks it's still running on my local machine:

What am I doing wrong?

Publishing to azure works as intended.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]    TestApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\TestApp\TestApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs:17

Comment: sometimes you see this if the error is in a compiled DLL, and it was compiled on your local machine, so the stack trace shows the code path as it was when it was compiled. Are you just asking us about why the path looks like that, or are you really asking how to fix the null reference exception? It's not clear. We can't fix the exception without a lot more detail, obviously.

Comment: I was asking about why the local path was in there...
How do I proceed in figuring out what's wrong since it works on my local machine and azure?